# Dtypewarning columns(1,2,3,4,5..............142)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have hundreds of asc file i want to concat them using python pandas
here is my code
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
joined_files = os.path.join("*.asc")
joined_list = glob.glob(joined_files)
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, joined_list), ignore_index=True)
print(df)

actually my files contains 43 columns and 8395 rows
it showing Dtype error
how can I solve it
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py:294: DtypeWarning: Columns (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,136,137,138,139,140,141,142) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.

Comment: Please add code in proper formatted way, to easily understand and help you with solution.

Comment: Try to follow the hint `Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below,

Considering your joined_list has all the paths of the files as list, then below code can be tried on top of it.

```
df_list = [pd.read_csv(x, dtype=str) for x in joined_list]
df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: no sir it doesn't work , still my output  first column contains  hundreds  of columns,but Dtypewarning is not showing

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the dataset ? for better providing the solution ?